# EF Code first migration fails

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am trying to update a database using EF6 and code first migrations.  The migration `A` goes through all the steps and I trace out when it gets to the end.  But it then errors out with this:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

Migration `B` is not even started, and when looking at the database, migration `A` has not been committed.

It also only seems to be affecting this one database, as 99% of our other customers have migrated without issue.  We have tried SQL2008 & 2014 with the same results.  The db model is written in C#, .NET 4.6, and EF6.1.3

Comment: If you run the migration script directly does it work? If so the migration history could be corrupted.

Comment: Code example please.

Comment: If it happens with only one particular db then there's a data error in there. Some constraint is not met. Impossible to tell form this question.

Comment: @stuartd Nope it doesn't!  Thanks, I completely forgot about doing that.  I was able to identify the issue.  Next question would be, why would the code migration run to completion, and only then error out, and not at the code statement that is generating the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

taking @stuartd's advice in the comments, I output the migration to a SQL script and ran it on the server.  Doing this isolated the cause of the failed migration.  The reason it did not error out at the exact line in code is because the migration takes place within a transaction.